# Do I need to buy extra content separately or does it come with the starter edition?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So when you have the starter edition of WOW and you want to upgrade to the full edition do you have to buy the extra Add-Ons or does it come for free when you buy the full game from the starter edition?

Comment: Please note that I didn't play WoW or I don't know jack about it, I have diablo 3 by the same company, it requires you to get expansions for extra money.

Answer (score 3):

Buying "World of Warcraft" from Blizzard's store includes the base game, The Burning Crusade, Wrath of the Lich King, Cataclysm, and Mists of Pandaria (basically, all the content up to level 90). Warlords of Draenor is sold separately.

Comment: thanks                                                                @originaluser

Comment: @CrustyCupcake511 Welcome to Arqade! If you thought this post answered your question, please accept it as the answer so that it shows as answered on the site :)

Answer (score 1):

If you first play the starter edition for a little while(free trial) the launcher store will give you the option to upgrade your account for HALF THE PRICE it currently is in store. By playing for a little while you can save abour 43-56% over buying the game first.

Its also may be cheaper to buy the warlords of draenor expansion at game stop for 29.99+ tax currently. Walmart also has the battle chest for $13 and change +tax.